# An eigen-decomposition/diagonalization question

Tags: self-learning, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm data analyst without any good math background. I'm struggling to understand and to code myself eigen-decompositions. So far, I know QR algorithm of eigen-decomposition.

**My problem**. Let $\bf A$ be non-symmetric *diagonalizible* square real matrix. I performed basic QR algorithm on it and got $\bf A=QTQ'$, where $\bf Q$ is orthogonal eigenvectors and $\bf T$ is upper-triangular, the eigenvalues of $\bf A$ being on its diagonal.

But instead of it I want to get eigen solution $\bf A=VDV^{-1}$, with non-orthogonal eigenvectors $\bf V$ but diagonal matrix $\bf D$ with those eigenvalues.

*Is it possible* to obtain the second solution from the first, how? *If not* possible - what then would be the eigen-decomposition algorithm to apply to get the second solution? Maybe a modification of QR or another one, relatively simple (and I'm not interested in complex numbers anyway)? What would you suggest?

Illustration:

```
A (taken from Wikipedia "Diagonizible matrix")
  1  2  0
  0  3  0
  2 -4  2

1. Do QR eigendecomposition
T (eigenvalues on the diagonal)
   3.0000  -1.4142   4.6188
    .0000   2.0000    .8165
    .0000    .0000   1.0000
Q (orthogonal)
    .4082   -.5774   -.7071
    .4082   -.5774    .7071
   -.8165   -.5774    .0000
A is restored by Q*T*Q' 

2. Use MATLAB function [V,D]=eig(A,'nobalance') [Don't know how it works]
D (diagonal, same eigenvalues)
   3.0000    .0000    .0000
    .0000   2.0000    .0000
    .0000    .0000   1.0000
V (nonorthogonal; still V*inv(V)=I)
   -.5000    .0000   -.5000
   -.5000    .0000    .0000
   1.0000  -1.0000   1.0000
A is restored by V*D*inv(V)

Can I transform results (1) into results (2)?
If no, please recommend/show algorithm to arrive at (2).
Thank you!
```

Comment: Do you really want non-orthogonal eigenvectors in $\mathbf{V}$, or are you mainly seeking a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ (and don't really care about the orthogonality of column vectors in $\mathbf{V}$)?

Comment: I need both: diagonal **D** and (non-orthogonal) eigenvectors **V**. So that I can restore **A** by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues, so they are the same as the diagonal elements of $T$.

Columns of $V$ are eigenvectors, but $A = V D V^{-1}$, called the [Jordan decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), is numerically unstable, meaning that you can do it with the highest possible precision and still get $A \ne V D V^{-1}$. So, be sure that you really must use it.

As for your question, you can find a Jordan decomposition of a triangular matrix $T$ (for example, see [here](http://math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f11/lect22-beamer.pdf)), which is easier than doing so for a general dense matrix.

My final advice would be: do not implement these yourself. Depending on what language or tool you are using, there are probably well though-of and well written functions that compute all of these decompositions. If there are not, you're probably using an inadequate tool. However, it still might be possible to call external programs written in more appropriate languages (i.e., Python, Matlab, Mathematica,...).

Comment: Vedran, thank you. I'll be studying your answer. Meanwile, I'd be happy to get your expertize of the following advice I was given: `You can post-process T from the Schur form to obtain an Y such that inv(Y)TY is diagonal. Details are in Golub & Van Loan, Matrix Computations, Sections 7.6.3 (Block Diagonalization) and 7.6.4 (Eigenvector Bases).` I got the book and am struggling to understand the sections. Can you comment on the advice? (Tell me if you can't find the book.) Note that my goal _is_ to implement it myself, not necessarily efficiently. This is my own self-study.

Comment: This is the same advice that I gave you. If you find $D = Y^{-1} T Y$, then $T = Y D Y^{-1}$ is a Jordan decomposition of $T$. I don't think there is an easier way than that. The chapters of the book are well chosen, but you probably need to read a bit more, since you said that you are "without any good math background" and this is not trivial stuff. You might want to go through Wikipedia article I linked above, as well as few linked from there. If you get stuck, you can always ask new questions and someone will probably answer.